# function to handle non-uniform jquery list

Tags: jquery, performance

I'm building a function that, for each item with a given class, loops through each of them, looking for the tallest one, then sets the rest to that same height.

The problem is that I'm only using a single class name and I am catching different elements types that should each be handled uniquely according to their element type (i.e. LIs vs DIVs)

```
var makeModulesSameHeight = function() {
    var maxHeight,
        $arrAllTargets = $(".makeEqualHeight");
    maxHeight = getMaxHeight($arrAllTargets);
    $arrAllTargets.css("height",maxHeight);
    console.log("max height for every friggin' thing is " + maxHeight);
};

var getMaxHeight = function($arrModules){
    var myHeight,maxHeight = 0;
    $arrModules.each(function(){
        myHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
        maxHeight = (myHeight > maxHeight) ? myHeight : maxHeight;
    });
    return maxHeight;
};


makeModulesSameHeight();
```

Fiddle-->  http://jsfiddle.net/scott_in_ct/bpKxQ/

Does anyone have a good way to make this work according to element type?

I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
// initialize empty list to contain unique tag names
// select jquery master list of all items with same class
// for each item in jquery master list
//     - if this tagName is not in list above, add it

// then

// for each item in tagName list
//     - create new array specific to that tagName 
          (not sure how to do this, actually.  I think I'm getting confused 
           with PHP's associative array.)  
          I guess I can always just remember what ordinal number 
            goes with which item.

// for each item in jquery master list
//     - move this item into its appropriate tag array
// for each tag array
//     - set each item in array to max height using previous implementation
```

This seems like a kludgy way to do this with multiple loops and such.  I'm looking to see if anyone has a more efficient approach, perhaps using memoization or something cool.  :^)

OR

```
// for each item in master array
//    -- look to a common parent and set height according to its descendents
//       (somehow)
// profit!
```

Comment: Let me clarify:  You want to create a list of <li>s and <div>s and you want all <li>s to have the same height as the tallest <li> and all <div>s to have the heights of the tallest <div>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are going to get an array of all elements with a clasname of .makeEqualHeight.  This array will have multiple different element types (i.e. divs, lis, etc.).  Now we want to find the best performing method to determine the height of the tallest element of its type.  If there are div's and li's then we want to retrieve two different max heights.

The trick here is that you get your array of elements, and get the max height by a filtered subset of that array of elements.

First we have to determine what the element types are in the array.  We do this by looping through the array and getting the property tagname.  If the tagname does not already exist in the array, add it to the array of element types.

```
$arrAllTargets.each(function () {
   var p = $(this).prop("tagName"); 
    if(arrElTypes.indexOf(p) < 0) {
         arrElTypes.push(p); 

    }
});
```

Now that we have an array of element types, lets loop through that array.  In each iteration we are going to filter the master array of elements by the element type.  We will call the getMaxHeight function using our filtered list.  Rinse and repeat.

```
for(i = 0; i < arrElTypes.length; i++) {
    maxHeight = getMaxHeight($arrAllTargets.filter(arrElTypes[i]));
    $arrAllTargets.filter(arrElTypes[i]).css("height",maxHeight);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bpKxQ/2/

edit: The heights look very similar, the LI elments are 140px and the div elements are 120px.  They are so close because you are using outerHeight().  Try using height() instead, since you are setting the height (not the outerHeight) when you edit the css attribute.

Comment: I like it. As I went to lunch, it occurred to me that I should probably use something like $.filter(), which I've never used before.  Thanks!